# Using reduce to get object with objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, reduce

I have array of the following form:

```
[
{key: "key1", value: value1}
{key: "key2", value: value2}
{key: "key3", value: value3}
...
]
```

I need to convert to the following form:

```
{ { key1 : value1},  { key2 : value2},  { key3 : value3} }
```

How to do it with **reduce()** ?

I am trying to use this code:

```
 var someObject = this.someArray.reduce(function(acc, item) {
            return { [item.key]: item.value};
        }, {});
```

but I always get **only the last item** instead of all of them.

Comment: All of your keys are *the same key*. Also using `+` on objects coerces them to strings `"[object Object]"`. It's unclear how you thought that might work.

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. Do you want an array of objects?

Comment: @jonrsharpe- I fixed the input keys

Comment: Give a [mre]. Adding commas and quotes to make it minimally valid syntax, this doesn't output only the last item, it outputs `"[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe would that not be the minimal reproducible example the OP is dealing with? Maybe they're unaware that you cannot use `+` to add objects?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer the input is syntactically invalid and the output doesn't match what they describe, so: no.

Comment: @Dane Brouwer- so sorry again - I edited the above example to the line that gave me only the last item.

Comment: This was that unexpected? You don't refer to the `acc`umulated value at all in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your return

```
return acc + { [item.key]: item.value};
```

You cannot use the `+` operator to `add` objects. Try the following:

```
acc[item.key] = item.value;
return acc
```

This assumes your `keys` are all unique. See full example below:

```js
let x = [{
    key: "key1",
    value: 'value1'
  },
  {
    key: "key2",
    value: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key: "key3",
    value: 'value3'
  },
].reduce((accumulatedValue, curentValue) => {
  accumulatedValue[curentValue.key] = curentValue.value;
  return accumulatedValue
}, {})
console.log(x);
```

Comment: When I try this I get error: ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.```

Comment: @codeKnight Well it can't be an issue with the change I suggested. There is likely an issue elsewhere. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the answer - but - in order to get rid of the error that I got in the comment here above - I had to add an explicit type - so I'm going to edit this answer with that.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation so the edit part won't show until it is approved - so I write here: I added: `{} as Record<string, string>` at the end ....

Answer (score 1):

Either you seek an array of object, then the following example applies :

```js
const res = [{
  key: 'key1',
  value: 'value1',
}, {
  key: 'key1',
  value: 'value1',
}, {
  key: 'key1',
  value: 'value1',
}].reduce((tmp, {
  key,
  value,
}) => [
  ...tmp,

  {
    [key]: value,
  },
], []);

console.log(res);
```

---

Either you seek an unique object, then the following example applies :

```js
const res = [{
  key: 'key1',
  value: 'value1',
}, {
  key: 'key2',
  value: 'value2',
}, {
  key: 'key3',
  value: 'value3',
}].reduce((tmp, {
  key,
  value,
}) => ({
  ...tmp,

  [key]: value,
}), {});

console.log(res);
```

---

About your code, as people told you already in the comments, you cannot simply use the `+` operator to concatenate either arrays or objects.

Comment: I removed the `+` from the code in question. it was a mistake. look now.

Comment: can you clarify your second answer ? what is the `...tmp' ?

Comment: The `...` is called the *spread operator*, what I do is creating a new array composed of all the elements from the accumulator plus a new element. It have the same result as using assignation (like Dane Brouwer answer). [here is some tutorial](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/7998/es6-tutorials-spread-operator-with-fun)